# Regarding .NET application

Tags: .net

I don't have registry access(regedit) because of this I face the some problem when I'm running my ASP .NET application. After running application gives me following error.

> Error 157 Cannot register assembly
>   "E:\Tushar\CheckCashing\Business\Legacy\MoneyTransferCommon\bin\Debug\Common.dll"
>   - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key
>   'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Common.Utils.StringUtils' is denied.   Common
>   (Legacy\Common)

Please give me the solution for this error. And also give me solution if there is no registry access then also can we able to access application codes.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your web app is running under an account with higher privileges.